# Bluetooth automatically getting onn after shutting down

Tags: bluetooth

Bluetooth getting onn automatically after shutting down the system.This happened after the last update of 18.04.Help!

Comment: ...Bluetooth turns on when the system is powered off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason could be bluetooth being in startup applications.

1. Go in Unity Dash, search for Startup Applications.
2. If you see blutooth manager there, click on remove.